# Working with date javascript strings, possible?

Tags: javascript, datetime, type-conversion, momentjs

I have a functie that keeps track of the local time live. I'm using the `new Date();` object to get the local *hours*, *minutes* and *seconds*.

I also want the user to give a input where a function has to start on a specific time. The input of the user is a *string* (I don't want the user to work with the `Date();` object as not all users can program). For example:

**Input user:**

`var timeStart = "10:08:30";`

**Live time converted to string:**

`var sTime = todayHours + ':' + todayMinutes + ':' + todaySeconds;`

**When the two are equal:**

```
if(sTime == timeStart )
{
   //function when equals time
   //This function has a timeout, so it will run infinite times
   var timeOutId = setTimeout(function()
            {
                //call functie

            }, 10000); //every 10 seconds as example
}
```

Alright this work just fine. I can compare strings only if they are the same or not. However to make it a little bit more complicated: I also want the user to give a end time, when to function has to stop:

**Input user:**

`var timeEnd = "11:08:30";`

**Live time converted to string:**

`var sTime = todayHours + ':' + todayMinutes + ':' + todaySeconds;`

**When the two are equal:**

```
if( sTime == timeEnd)
{
   //function when equals time
   //calls the timeout id and stops it
   clearTimeout(timeOutId);
}
```

---

Now this just works fine! However now you know what i'm trying to do i'm wondering if i can do in some way:

```
if(sTime >= timeStart && sTime <= timeEnd)
{
  //timeout will only be set when it's in between the given time
  setTimeout(function()
    {
        //call functie
    }, 10000); //every 10 seconds as example
}
```

### Question

I there a way i can transform my string time(using 2-digits method) in a excisting date time so i can compare it on time?

*My time only uses [hour, minutes and seconds], which causes problems as the Date(year, month and day) is not defined.*

I've tryed to use *Momentjs* but it also refuses to work with only hour, minutes and seconds. Or i might not be farmilier on how to do this.

The method i want to use seems much easier as i don't have to define when to cancel the `timeOut`.

Any help is appreciated!

**P.s What i actually just have to accomplish is converting the string time to a *unix time stamp*** 
(Of course other methods are welcome too).

Comment: _“My time only uses [hour, minutes and seconds], which causes problems as the Date(year, month and day) is not defined”_ – well then use the year, month, day values of the actual date for those.

Comment: I see what you mean here. But i still would have to break the string to define each part. I could just take the get the hours, minutes and seconds out of the string. convert the string to int where i convert it to seconds. same with the minutes. Where i then just compare the seconds with each other. But i wonder if the direct string can be seen as a date.

Comment: Well if you are just working with time spans within a day, you could convert your input to seconds and use those for comparison. And splitting up a string with a strictly defined format is quite easy.

Comment: I think i just answered my question, yes... Sometimes you just have to write your problem down to get a clear look again. You really helped me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know moment.js but you could still use basic parseInt to extract the time , turn it into and integer so you can compare it with another one :

```
function stringtime_to_seconds(aString){
 var time,a = aString.split(":");
 switch(a.length){
    default: // 3 , you'll need to handle other cases
    time = parseInt(a[0])*3600+parseInt(a[1])*60+parseInt(a[2]);
 }
 return time;
}
```

then you can compare dates.

Comment: Look at my comment just before you posted. It's excatly how i thought i could solve it ^^ Btw shouldn't the hour to seconds should be *3600 (60*60) instead of *1200? A non-case function would be fine here as it's stricted as @CBroe noted :)

Comment: sure ! did not see the message before

Comment: Thanks for the edit :) accepted your answer as I would not know the `split()` function put all results into a array.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tryed to use Momentjs but it also refuses to work with only hour, minutes and seconds. Or i might not be farmilier on how to do this.
>   ...
>   What i actually just have to accomplish is converting the string time to a unix time stamp

You simply need to provide the format string, such as:

```
// parse the input
var timeStart = "10:08:30";
var m = moment(timeStart,"HH:mm:ss");

// then one of these
var s = m.unix();      // unix time in seconds
var ms = m.valueOf();  // unix time in milliseconds
```

Of course, to get unix time you have to have a specific date in mind.  With the above method, it will use the local time zone's "today".  This might be a concern if you have a range that spans over midnight, such as 10pm - 2am, so you might need to adjust.

Also, you said you were doing a range comparison like:

```
if(sTime >= timeStart && sTime <= timeEnd)
```

You probably should not do that with strings.  But also, you should use a half-open interval `[start,end)`.  In other words:

```
if(sTime >= timeStart && sTime < timeEnd)
```

Usually when someone says 1:00 to 2:00, they mean that the range is *over* at 2:00.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to let me know how to do it with momentjs :) However, i think the hard coded way is faster as it doesn't needs to calculate the whole unix time but only 3 integers. I did not know about the half-open interval, but sure is a nice detail i did not know of! thanks!